# Change the AllowedNetworkTypes for requests in queue or already running in download manager

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I have a setting in my app that allow the user to choose to download things using WiFi only or also on Mobile Data.

I want when the user changes this setting, to reflect it immediately on the requests currently being downloaded or pending waiting to be downloaded.

**EDIT**
I am using the DownloadManager class, what I am asking for is to change the allowed networks for items with status STATUS_PENDING or STATUS_RUNNING in DownloadManager.

Answer (score 0):

I expect that you are executing this download in a service. If not, please change for it following the android services tutorial: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

After using a service you should have a configuration (a boolean should do the job) that you will check when executing the download. Following this approach you have a lot of options to change this configuration, in my option that are two good ones:

1: bind the service in the activity that has the option to change the wifi and call a method in the service to change the configuration

2: launch an intent to the service with the new configuration in the bundle. I would follow this one since you do not have to implement all the bind interface methods.

If you want more info, please post the important parts of your code in your question.

Comment: Understood, however please check my updates on the question